# C#, max, find rectangle in list with biggest area

Tags: c#, max

I have a list of rectangles "collidedrects"
I want to pass the one with the greatest area to the function _playership.Collide()
So far I have...

```
var item = collidedrects.Max(x => x.Height*x.Width);
_playership.Collide(collidedrects[item]);
```

I'm not familiar with max and also the => thing in C#

Comment: @Justin This won't work because `Max` returns the maximum value, rather than the object with the maximum value or (as OP's code seems to exepct) the index of the object with the maximum value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Aggregate` instead of `Max` to find the largest rectangle:

```
var largestRect = collidedrects.Aggregate( (r1,r2) => 
    (r1.Height * r1.Width) > (r2.Height * r2.Width) ? r1 : r2);
_playership.Collide(largestRect);
```

Comment: I'd never seen this before today and now it's come up twice. I love it. (Hah, I just noticed you posted in the same question as I saw this in...)

Comment: It works like Matlab in a way...more functional aspect. Correct me if I am wrong please. Agree with @Rawling nice bits and pieces :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Max` returns the value that you compared with, not the item that generated the value.  If you create a function `MaxBy` that returns the item that generated the value then it will work just fine.

```
public static TSource MaxBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> selector, IComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
{
    comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<TKey>.Default;
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> sourceIterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!sourceIterator.MoveNext())
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence was empty");
        }
        TSource max = sourceIterator.Current;
        TKey maxKey = selector(max);
        while (sourceIterator.MoveNext())
        {
            TSource candidate = sourceIterator.Current;
            TKey candidateProjected = selector(candidate);
            if (comparer.Compare(candidateProjected, maxKey) > 0)
            {
                max = candidate;
                maxKey = candidateProjected;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

With that you can do:

```
var item = collidedrects.MaxBy(x => x.Height*x.Width);
_playership.Collide(collidedrects[item]);
```